# need help in Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I am in a weird scenerio where I need to show the content in multiple columns. I am using css3 column-cont   and jquery plugin columnizer for older versions of IE.
The problem is that I do not have complete control over the data as it is served by an external webservice.
In most cases the content is wrapped in multiple paragraph tabs

`Content#1`

```
 <p><strong>Heading</strong><br>This is a content</p>
 <p><strong>Heading</strong><br>This is a content</p>
```

But In few cases the data is not wrapped in `<p>` tag and looks like below:

`Content#2`

```
<strong>Day 1: xyz </strong><br>
 lorem lipsum <br> <br> 
<strong>Dag 2: lorem lipsum</strong><br> 
Morgonflyg till Arequipa i södra Peru.
<br> <br>
```

The real problem is `jquery columnizer` plugin hangs up the browser with this markup when it is asked to columnize such content.

Now I want to transform `Content#2` to `Content#1` with the help of regular expression,ie wrap the contents into sensible paragraphs. I hope I have made myself clear
I am using PHP.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do _not_ parse HTML with regex. Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: What have you tried? Also, in order to approach a task like this, you need to define the logic by which a regular expression pattern might be built. What are the rules as to what it should match? That said, REGEX is normally a poor choice when it comes to parsing mark-up. You might be better off with PHP's DOMDocument class, though if your mark-up is invalid you might struggle.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo please give me some hint, I'm not just trying to parse here

Comment: You'll also have to define how is a "sensible paragraph".

Comment: Which WYSIWYG editor u r using to manage content... content comes from DB right?

Comment: @Utkanos I just thought regular expression would get solution for this problem but I don't know how to start

Comment: @Codesen I don't have any idea about which WYSIWYG editor is being used, I'm using the data from the webservice, and I don't have the control over it. I'm just trying to be safe from my side

Comment: Is there any common pattern of the content you are getting?

Comment: sample content from WS

Comment: `<strong>Dag 1: Avresa från Skandinavien till Lima</strong><br> Flyg till Lima med korti Amsterdan. Ankomst på kvällen till Lima. [Måltider på flyget]<br> <br> <strong>Dag 2: Världsarvstaden Lima och middag på piren vid Stilla havet</strong><br> Upptäcktsfärd till fots genom<br> <br> <strong>Dag 3: Arequipa och Santa Catalinaklostret</strong><br>  Eftermiddagen fri för egna strövtåg i de vackra omgivningarna. [F]<br> <br> <strong>Dag 4: Genom Colcadalen till Chivay</strong><br> Dagen<br> <br> <strong>Dag 5: Längs högplatån Altiplano till Puno vid Titicacasjön.</strong><br> Dagen inleds med be`

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary In case of faulty data:<strong>heading</strong><br>content<br><br> this pattern gets repeated

Comment: Tags on different lines is a perfect example of why we say **don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
/(?<!^<p>)(<strong>.*?)(<strong>.*)$/gs
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lO1zZ8)

Notice that the exclusion in the negative lookbehind will ONLY work if your strings starts with a `<p>`... so consider to *trim* it before applying your regex...

`<br>` tags has to be removed using another regex or [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Also, consider maybe using another aproach than Regex to parse DOM HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Your content is not stable and Regular Expression won't do magics with distinct contents like this. With this being said, whenever you're receiving the data from the other website, there might be a high chance that someday it'll return different pattern so your rules won't be good anymore. You need to have a reliable source to get a reliable result.

This is a filthy string manipulation but it'll get what you need if the pattern stays consistent. And, I still insist that you have to use a reliable source.

```
$str = "<strong>Day 1: xyz </strong><br>
 lorem lipsum <br> <br>
<strong>Dag 2: lorem lipsum</strong><br>
Morgonflyg till Arequipa i södra Peru.
<br> <br> ";

function parse($data)
{
  if(substr($data, 0, 3) == "<p>") return $data;

  $chunks = explode("<strong>", $data);
  $out = array();

  foreach($chunks as $chunk)
  {
    $item = $chunk;

    $last_br = strpos($item, "<br> <br>");
    if($last_br > -1){ $item = substr($item, 0, $last_br); }

    $item = "<p>" . $item . "</p>";

    $out[] = $item;
  }

  return implode("\n", $out);
}

echo parse($str);
```

Comment: So what and how do you suggest to get rid of the problem. So far, there are only two patterns of the data received from the webservice

    `<p><strong>heading</strong>content</p>`

and

   `<strong>heading</strong><br>content<br><br>`

Comment: @DipeshKc I said it in my answer the part about _reliable_. Anyway, you can somehow do this with string manipulation but it'll take your time. Maybe I'd be able to provide something for you, it'll take a while but I'm going to post it.